# Bootstrap Modal not displaying correctly on Android Webview

Tags: android, css, twitter-bootstrap, webview, titanium

I'm currently using **Titanium SDK** to use a webview that displays my remote website. The website has a twitter-bootstrap modal/popup on it.
When I view it on a desktop/mobile browser everything is fine, modal works and everything. Now when I view it in this **Android WebView on Titanium SDK 3.5.0,*** about 3/4 of the modal/popup is cut off for some reason:

Here's my Titanium Javascript code:
**web.xml and web.js:**
pastebin.com/RYG6EwAr

It works fine on an emulator, but on my physical Nexus 4 device it gets cut off (emulator runs Nexus 4 JellyBean 4.1, physical runs Nexus 4 Lollipop).

Here's how it looks on my physical device:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qe3Pz.jpg

Why is my modal getting cut off like that? I took the exact code from the Bootstrap site. If I point my webview here though:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

And I scroll down to the Example Modal button and click it, the modal looks fine! Doesn't get cut off or anything!

Here's my HTML code for the one that's getting cut off:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
    ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<! -- /Modal -->


<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //alert("test");
    });
    </script>


  </body>

</html>
```

What's going on? Why is it getting cut off on my page but not that getbootstrap.com page?

Comment: Here is also a website that cuts the modal off on the webview in android as well (uses the exact same code in this post for the HTML):
http://testdev98.x10host.com/test.html

The modal loads and everything, it just isn't displaying right in the Android webview (getting cut off, check the image in my first post at the top to see what I mean by cut off)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.
Turns out Titanium's Webview is not correctly setting the height of the body to comply with the height of the content.

I fixed it by setting the body's min-height to be the modal's height onload in my HTML file.